# Entity Framework Code First deleting one to zero/one child from parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have created a simple one to zero/one relationship inside of code first.  The code below works in that I can have a Person instance and optionally have an Account and its modeled fine in the database.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }
}
//Mapping
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasOptional(x => x.Account).WithRequired(x => x.Owner);
```

What I would like to do is to be able to delete the optional child from the parent.  I would expect this to work.

```
using (Context ctx = new Context())
{
    var personToDeleteFrom = ctx.Persons.Single(x => x.Id == <personid>);
    personToDeleteFrom.Account = null;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, the child object of the relationship is simply left in the database. Is there a way to make this work?  If not, what is the best practice for handling this type of relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually removing the child data just by setting the navigation property equal to null. You need to actually delete the data to get it to go away.

Just change the setting of the null to a `Remove` on the `Accounts` collection instead.

```
using (Context ctx = new Context())
{
    var personToDeleteFrom = ctx.Persons.Single(x => x.Id == <personid>);
    ctx.Accounts.Remove(personToDeleteFrom.Account);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

This will remove the `Account`.

This is due to the behavior of how Entity Framework handles 1:1 relationships. EF doesn't actually add foreign key fields in the database as they are unnecessary. Instead it just maintains the relationship that the primary key for an `Account` always equals the primary key for the associated `Person`.

You can see this behavior arise if you attempt to do the following.

```
using (Context ctx = new Context())
{
    var person = ctx.Persons.Single(x => x.Id == <personid>);
    person.Account = null;
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    person.Account = new Account();
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

This will throw a `System.Date.Core.Entity.UpdateException` as it attempts to add an entry to the Accounts table with a primary key set to <personid> when one already exists.

As such, nulling out the navigation property doesn't actually do anything. The relationship is maintained by keeping the primary keys of each entity in sync. To actually remove the Account you need to delete it from the table.

Comment: No, that won't throw a referential integrity violation.  It will throw a duplicate primary key exception, because you now have more than one record with the same primary key.  EF does nothing to keep these in sync, and relies on the database to do so via primary key constraints.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Correct, EF isn't the one maintaining the fact that the foreign key in the Account table needs to exist in the Persons table that is the database. What EF is in fact doing is making sure that the Id on Person and the Id on Account are equal. You can easily profile the SQL generated by EF to see that the Id being inserted when you assign a new Account to the persons Account property has the same Id as the Person. This is how EF is maintaining the idea of a 1:1 relationship. If the Ids have to be equal then there is no chance of their being anything but a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: If you look at the table definitions for the tables created by the above entities, the Id column on People (because EF is smart enough to call it people instead of Persons, go figure) is defined as IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL where as the Id column of Account is just NOT NULL. I assume this is so that EF can manage the Id values of Account to maintain this relationship.

Comment: Yes, but this is not a referential integrity violation If you try to add a second account.  It is a duplicate primary key constraint violation.  EF does assign the generated ID from the required end to the optional end during the insert process, but it doesn't do any referential integrity tracking as the database handles things.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch If you look I  edited the answer to reflect the exact exception that is thrown after your initial comment. My primary concern with your comment is that you said that EF did nothing to keep these in sync which is incorrect. The database makes sure that the Id on Account exists, but that Id is assigned by EF, not the database.